# How to select data dynamic data from the drop down list?

Tags: selenium-ide

I am new to selenium IDE, while i am performing some tests on maps.google site, when i enter data in the search box, it will display data related to that.
for eg: when i type "india", it will display a list of addition data related to the provided data, like "india bank" "india infoline" etc.
Say if i want to select any perticular data from the drop down what will be the command and target for that.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) type "india" using typekeys (it is more close to keyboard input)

2) WaitForElementPresent ([your xpath][1] or [your xpath] index=1) - include first element of the drop-down list to be sure it exists. Keep in mind that Selenium often runs faster than your application and/or browser so use WaitForElementPresent any time you have something refreshing or loading.

3) select your element select [your xpath] index=1

But make sure that value entered should result in non-empty list (you may have no "india" records).

===================

Here is the code you should use (I checked it on my side):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.google.com.ua/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>/</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>waitForElementPresent</td>
<td>gbqfq</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>gbqfq</td>
<td>bitragunta</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>waitForElementPresent</td>
<td>//html/body/div5/table/tbody/tr/td/div</td>
<td>index=1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>mouseOver</td>
<td>//html/body/div5/table/tbody/tr/td/div</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>mouseDown</td>
<td>//html/body/div5/table/tbody/tr/td/div</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
```

1) please change in my initial code one line from `<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.google.com.ua/" />` to `<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://maps.google.com/" />` 
If it does not help, try this:

2) try using this locator: //div[@id='hm']/table/tbody/tr/td/div

If does not work, then try this

3) try execute step by step my script (using menu Actions - Execute this command). And when list is displayed, explore it with Firebug or similar tool to find out its xpath. Maybe Google has different pages for different countries?

===================================================

1) about error.[error] Element //html/body/div5/table/tbody/tr/td/div not found:
this element can be found only when list is expanded (i.e. after you type something in search textbox)

2) what do you mean by asking about the right way? Of course I would not advice anything that sounds wrong for me. The only thing you may want to change is to use simpler locator for the list. But try to make it work first.

3) What code are you not able to add? Please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have performed the actions but the issue is not solved, please find the commands below,                                                           <tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>gbqfq</td>
 <td>bitragunta</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>//html/body/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td/div</td>
 <td>index=1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>select</td>
 <td>//html/body/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td/div</td>
 <td>index=1</td>
</tr>
My base url is https://maps.google.com/

Comment: I appreciate for your time and efforts,

Comment: I appreciate for your time and efforts, When i applied this code still the the result is same, Selenium is unable to select the option and it throws the error as"[error] Element //html/body/div5/table/tbody/tr/td/div not found" as a result it is not selecting the options.                                                               I tried to find the Xpath provided by you it is not available,may i know for which element you have given the Xpath.                                                                  thanks

Comment: Sorry, it was formatting error. Correct locator is:

//html/body/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td/div

Comment: Hi Qarea                                                                   Still i am getting the below error.[error] Element //html/body/div[5]/table/tbody/tr/td/div not found

Comment: Hi Qarea I have followed the below code which works for me,is this the right way to do this?

Comment: i am unable to add the code, here dont know as it says that too many characters while i do that in comments box and i dont know how to do that other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know it work for you or not.

```
 <tr>
       <td>open</td>
       <td>https://maps.google.co.in/</td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
            <td>assertTitle</td>
           <td>Google Maps</td>
            <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
            <td>type</td>
            <td>id=gbqfq</td>
            <td>indian restaurant</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>pause</td>
       <td>1000</td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
        <td>javascript:prompt(&quot; Enter what you want to from dropdown&quot;)
    </td> 
        <td>dropdown</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>type</td>
   <td>id=gbqfq</td>
   <td>${dropdown}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
          <td>click</td>
      <td>id=gbqfb</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Hi Ankit the you code works fine but the the thing is it doesnot meet my requirement, say in your code you have type "Indian restarunt", where as in the drop down there are some more options are there, like "tandoori restaruant"
"HandiIndian restarunt" etc, say if i want to select any of this option then how could i able to do that?

Comment: you can not select value from the drop down, you have to write manually value in the search box. selenium IDE do not select automatically value from the auto scroller.

Comment: @user2238927 i make some changes in the code please review it

Comment: Hi Ankit,                                                                The updated code works, but the thing is cant we select the options rather than typing the options?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>https://maps.google.co.in/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript:prompt(&quot; Enter what you want to search&quot;)</td>
    <td>search</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>${search}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript:prompt(&quot;Enter which you want from drop down&quot;)</td>
    <td>googlesearch</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>${googlesearch}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=gbqfb</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Nikhil,                                                                I ran your code where as it ask to type the options, which i can do right by giving type command, here i want to select the given option, could you please let me know how we can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and came up with this solution:

```
storeText | Xpath (ex: //div[3]/div/select/option[4]) | variable

selectAndWait| id=(drop down)|label=${variable}
```

Since the option in the drop down changes every time the page loads, storing the option and then calling that variable every time you test will select the correct option from your drop down every time. The only limitation to this is if the options in the drop down are not always in the same order. If you are just looking to select the first option ALWAYS, in the Xpath use

```
.../option[1]
```

Hope this helps